# Testing Soap 1.2 service in RobotFramework using suds library

Tags: soap, robotframework, webservice-client, suds

I am trying to test soap 1.2 services using RobotFramework. So far, we have only tested soap 1.1 services using suds library for RobotFramework, and suds is not compatible with soap 1.2.

Backwards compatibility is an option for the new services, but it would be better to have a more long-term solution. I am not an experienced programmer, though I can edit code if told what to edit and where.

What happens in the test we have for soap 1.2 services using suds is: suds is unable to interpret the response it gets from the webservice and gives this error: SAXParseException: :159:229: mismatched tag

The soap message is fine, there is no problem using it in SoapUI.

I have found some snippets online that suggest I could get suds library to work with soap 1.2 for my RobotFramework tests. But I have little programming experience and no idea how to incorporate those snippets in suds.
Someone commented on this snippet that this fixed his issue with RobotFramework and suds.

Is there someone out there willing to explain how I could make this work? I can't seem to figure it out on my own. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.bindings import binding
import logging


USERNAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'

# Just for debugging purposes.
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Telnic's SOAP server expects a SOAP 1.2 envelope, not a SOAP 1.1 envelope
# and will complain if this hack isn't done.
binding.envns = ('SOAP-ENV', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope')
client = Client('client.wsdl',
        username=USERNAME,
        password=PASSWORD,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml'})

# This will now work just fine.
client.service.someRandomMethod()
```

snippet from: https://gist.github.com/kgaughan/858851

Comment: Which Python version are you on?

Comment: Validating the key difference between 1.1 and 1.2 is the HTTP header value for `Content-Type` was changed to `'application/soap+xml'`. That should be the focus of your investigation. My experiences with SudsLibrary haven't been good so I'd suggest trying a fork or evaluate a custom implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We are at 2.7. Upgrading isn't an option right now. For testing purposes Suds worked fine so far (robotframework-sudslibrary). I have tried focussing on changing the HTTP header to application/soap+xml, but so far I havent figured out how to do this in a way that works. Custom implementation was actually what I was trying to do by integrating named snippet. I just don't know *how*  to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short Suds does not support SOAP 1.2 bindings. Development has ceased quite some time ago. For this reason the SudsLibrary does not support it either.

Some of the differences I observed using an [example service SOAP 1.1/1.2](http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx) are:

1. HTTP header `Content-Type`:

   - 1.2 = `"application/soap+xml"`
   - 1.1 = `"text/xml"`.
2. HTTP header

   - 1.2  = `Action`
   - 1.1  = `SOAPAction`
3. `Envelope Namespace`

   - 1.2 = `"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"`
   - 1.1 = `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`

For each of these a seperate solution was implemented in the example below. The content type could be overwritten. The Action can be added but the SOAPAction can not be removed. The namespace can also be overwritten using the extension library. This should work for you if your service ignores the SOAPaction header attribute.

**Test Case.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SudsLibrary
Library    SudsLibraryExtension
Library    Collections    

*** Test Cases ***
TC
    ${BASE_URL}    Set Variable         http://www.holidaywebservice.com
    ${SERVICE}     Create Dictionary    
    ...                                 name=HolidayService_v2    
    ...                                 wsdl=HolidayService2.asmx?WSDL
    ${PORT}        Set variable         HolidayService2Soap12
    ${METHOD}      Set variable         GetCountriesAvailable

    Set Binding     SOAP-ENV    http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
    Create Soap Client     ${BASE_URL}/${SERVICE.name}/${SERVICE.wsdl}
    Set Port    ${PORT}

    Set Headers    Content-Type    application/soap+xml
    Set Headers    Soapaction      ${EMPTY}
    Set Headers    Action          "${BASE_URL}/${SERVICE.name}/${METHOD}"

    ${result}          Call Soap Method     ${METHOD}
```

**SudsLibraryExtension.py**

```
import suds.bindings
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn, RobotNotRunningError

class SudsLibraryExtension(object):
    """
    Extension on the SudsLibrary

    """
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'    
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 1.0

    def __init__(self, LibraryName='SudsLibrary'):
        """SudsLibraryExtension can be imported with an optional argument.
        - ``LibraryName``:
          Default value for `LibraryName` is SudsLibrary if not given.
          The name can by any Library Name that implements or extends the
          SudsLibraryExtension.
        """        
        try:
            self.SudsLibrary = BuiltIn().get_library_instance(LibraryName)

        # This is useful for when you run Robot in Validation mode or load
        # the library in an IDE that automatically retrieves the documen-
        # tation from the library. 
        except RobotNotRunningError:
            pass

    def set_binding(self, binding, url):
        """Set Binding can be used to add a binding to the message.

        Example    Set Binding     SOAP-ENV    http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
        """
        suds.bindings.binding.envns = (binding, url)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! The service we were working on has been put back to 1.1 for the time being. I will try the solutions and update after doing so, as soon as the next soap 1.2 service is available (which should be within a few weeks).